# Can hybrids from closely related species with similar chromosomes reproduce?

Tags: genetics, plant-physiology, meiosis, speciation, polyploidy

Let's say the plant Triticum monococcum which has 2 sets of 7 chromosomes when diploid and 1 set of 7 chromosomes when haploid has the genome AA. When interbred with a different species that has the same sets and number of chromosomes when diploid and haploid but instead has the genome BB, the hybrid produced would have a genome of AB and 2 sets of 7 chromosomes as well, just that the sets of chromosomes would be genetically different although similar. This hybrid is known to be sterile.

I thought that because both parents had the same number of chromosomes which are similar, the hybrid would be able to reproduce, just not an offspring that is also like itself (unless an autopolyploidy event occurs).

To show what I mean, given that the hybrid has the genome AB, 2n=14, it would undergo meiosis and given that no variations occur the result would lead to gamete 1 which has recombinants of the chromosomes, and gamete 2 which has the remaining chromosomes. Would not these gametes be able to reproduce with others?